# I am sending a valid PUT request to the GitHub API, but GitHub is not merging my pull request

Tags: ruby, github-api

Please ignore the ugly Ruby code, it's only here for illustration purposes of my attempt to merge a pull request using the GitHub API.

```
def merge_pull_request(github_profile_name, repo_name, pull_request_number, personal_access_token)
    uri = URI("https://api.github.com/repos/#{github_profile_name}/#{repo_name}/pulls/#{pull_request_number}/merge?personal_access_token=#{personal_access_token}")
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
       :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
       request = Net::HTTP::Put.new uri

       response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

       puts response.body
    end
end
```

When I input in the correct parameters though, this is the response I get:

```
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button"}
```

What happened?

Comment: You might want to use a Ruby GitHub library rather than roll (and test!) your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub API's response is misleading. What is actually going on is that my personal access token is not *authorized* to merge pull requests. This was a silly error on my part...my personal access token was only authorized specifically for "user scope", but I forgot to click on the checkbox for  the "repo scope". "Scopes" are how GitHub defines whether you have access to a specific field (such as the ability to control a User's profile or to merge a Pull Request), and so it is very essential to manage your personal access token's scopes properly if you want GitHub API to behave.

You can access profile information about your personal access token by going into Settings -> Personal Access Token, and then edit your Personal Access Token to grant and revoke "scopes".